# Converting IMU coordinate to Unity Coordinate

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, rotation, quaternions, imu

Hi i tried to align IMU coordinate to Unity coordinate.
What i want to do is

1. IMU coordinate(right hand) to Unity coordinate (left hand)
2. IMU is attached to my hand so get the hand orientation(quaternion) using IMU (quaternion)
3. IMU is attached to my hand so get the hand acc data using IMU acc

First I convert the IMU coordinate to unity coordinate

```
(x,y,z,w)_IMU -> (y,-z,-x,w)_Unity
```

and

```
(initial) * (y,-z,-x,w)
```

(`initial` is quaternion of hand when hand is showing up)

I think `(y,-z,-x,w)` represent the angle change in unity coordinate and multiply it with hand orientation so it algin well with hand rotation.

**And this process works well when I check my real hand and fake hand in unity coordinates.**

Next I want to convert IMU acceleration to unity acceleration

```
(x,y,z)_IMU -> (-y,z,x)_Unity
```

right hand to left hand

```
(IMU coordinate get from top) * (-y,z,x) * (IMU coordinate get from top)^-1
```

So i think this process can align IMU acceleration data to unity global coordinate.

But I am not sure this process is correct. So any help or comment about this is very thankful for me!

Unity coordinate:

[image]

IMU coordinate

[image]

Verify that the math process that i used is correct

Comment: Since the acceleration is aligned with the local coordinates of the hand in unity, i tried to multiply the value of the acceleration by the quaternion value of the hand to get the unity global directional acceleration, but it doesn't work well. 
(global acc) = (hand quarternio) * (hand acc)

Comment: In your IMU coordinates graphic is it correct to assume that `Y+` points **forward** and `z+` points **upward** and accordingly `x+` points to the **right**? It's a bit hard to tell from the graphic ^^ And can you share you actual code and indicate what exactly you mean by `But I am not sure this process is correct.` .. are the results you get correct or not?

Comment: I would assume you should either only invert X (in case the IMU is Y-up, Z-forward) or you would flip Y<->Z but not negate them (in case the IMU is Z-up, Y-forward) ... but I'm also no math expert ^^ I just overlaid the two systems on a drawing and that seems to make sense: `Matrix4x4 conversionMatrix = new Matrix4x4(new Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0), new Vector4(0, 0, 1, 0), new Vector4(0, 1, 0, 0), new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1));`